# Vector 2, вращение объекта как в иерархий, как? SDL2

Tags: c#, c++, sdl2

Как реализовать вращение объекта на двухмерном пространстве имитируя иерархию объектов | SDL2

```
        Vec2 arranged(x,y);
        Vec2 rotated =Vec2::RotateUp(renderSource->transform()->localAngle()*Mathf::Deg2Rad, arranged);
        arranged.x -= rotated.x;
        arranged.y += rotated.y;

        //arranged = Vec2::Perpendicular(arranged);
        //Положение по горизонтале
        wrapper.dst.x = arranged.x + ((rect.w - wrapper.dst.w) / 2.0f - (point.x - sourcePoint.x) * squarePerPixels);
        //Положение по вертикале
        wrapper.dst.y = arranged.y + ((rect.h - wrapper.dst.h) / 2.0f + (point.y - sourcePoint.y) * squarePerPixels);

        // SDL_RenderCopyF(renderer, renderInfo.texture, (SDL_Rect*)&renderInfo.src, (SDL_FRect*)&dst);
        SDL_RenderCopyExF(renderer, wrapper.texture->native(), (SDL_Rect*)&wrapper.src,
                          reinterpret_cast<SDL_FRect*>(&wrapper.dst), renderSource->transform()->localAngle(), nullptr,
                          SDL_RendererFlip::SDL_FLIP_NONE);
```

Центральный объекто смотрит вверх, и его хвост правильный а остальные имеют проблемы

[image: Центральный объекто смотрит вверх, и его хвост правильный а остальные имеют проблемы]

Comment: Нужон [mcve] для ваших "трансформов" и прочего.

Comment: Ответ решен! Следующий раз буду заполнять подробностями! Спасиб!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самое простое решение -- добавить хвост в иерархию этого насекомого.
Выглядеть должно примерно следующим образом:

```
Monster
- MonsterBody
- MonsterTail
```

Правка:
Исходя из обсуждения предлагаю изменить функцию RotateUp следующим образом:

```
const Vector2 Vector2::RotateAround(Vector2 center, Vector2 localPosition, float angle)
{
    float Sin = Mathf::Sin(angle);
    float Cos = Mathf::Cos(angle);
    return new Vector2(center.x + (localPosition.x * Sin), center.y +
        (localPosition.y * Cos));
}
```

где localPosition это изначальный вектор смешения объекта относительно center

Comment: Я бы конечно этого сделал бы, так как я пишу движок с нуля. И у меня проблемы с этим. Иерархия есть, но нет способа этого отрендерить. Вращать каждый дочерный объект

Comment: В таком случае предлагаю следующие решения:
1. сместить точку вращения хвоста в центр тела
2. сделать 2 спрайта одним целым

Comment: это подойдет как решения, только при общих (склейных) спрайтах. Но я планирую использовать анимированные спрайты. Где части тела будут *изме-няться*. Т.е я делаю игрушку по типу змейки.

Comment: В таком случае предлагаю следующее:
3. при каждом обновлении менять позицию хвоста на ((позиция тела).x * sin(угла поворота тела), (позиция тела).y * cos(угла поворота тела)) + (позиция тела). В зависимости от твоей системы исчисления поворота формула может выглядеть по-другому

Comment: Уточните что такое v

Comment: v - Вектор которое будет вращаться на заданный угол angle

Comment: @LightMister Если пишите с нуля, то из тегов вопроса следует убрать метки unity3d, sdl2 и одну из меток не относящегося к вопросу языка.

Comment: Стоит также добавить, что функцию можно сделать работающей через глобальные координаты, но это раз вы делаете иерархию, то я так понимаю, что у вас уже есть нужные средства

Comment: @alexandr-kosolobov иерархия устроена не сложно. Я брал пример с Unity, тот же вид ООП, только немного измененный в среде. Изложу пример иерархий
Пример  иерархий в движке
<pre>
Object* - базовый объект в движке
 Component* - Компоненты, которые будут прикрепляться к GameObject
 ...
 Transform - Компонент для расположение объекта в пространстве, он же и содержит иерархию объектов (с этим сейчас проблемы, текущуая тема об этом) 
GameObject - игровой объект аналогичен в UnityEngine->GameObject
<pre>

Comment: Прошу прощения, но разбираться в архитектуре новоиспеченного графического движка -- не моя компетенция

Comment: @alexandr-kosolobov
есть успех в поправленном коде. Вариант RotateAround, исправил 50% проблемы, результат по ссылке 
https://imgur.com/3uy2Wsp
Но при вращений направо, налево объект смещается

Comment: @alexandr-kosolobov
получилось. Я поправил изменения. Спасибо за код! 
От всего лучшего, Ваш котик! Мур